# VBA web scrape REFERENCE

Tags: vba, excel

After navigating to the website, I have a list of names in a spreadsheet I need to populate into the search field, how do I reference the spreadsheet in the macro?

from the Navigate command, I have the Url, it asks for first name, last name which i have populated in the spreadsheet.

How do I reference the cells from the spread sheet?:

```
first_name= **A1** &last_name= **B1** &state=TX&country_code=US
```

something similar to this, with a loop statement? A1 B1 as example

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to ask. You should include the code you have written so far, so we can see what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: updated post above

Comment: You should edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), 
to give us something solid to work with.  Let us know anything that you've already tried, any issues you encountered, 
and anything else you can think of that would help to illustrate your problem.  The more information you can provide,
the better we'll be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This simple instruction should do what you need.

**Code:**

```
Sub GrabName()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range, retVal As String, tRows As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    tRows = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To tRows

        retVal = "first_name=" & ws.Cells(r, 1)
        retVal = retVal & "$last_name=" & ws.Cells(r, 2)
        retVal = retVal & "&state=TX&country_code=US"
        retVal = Replace(retVal, " ", "%20")

        MsgBox retVal

    Next r

End Sub
```

Notice that I included a replacement for any *spaces* `" "` to change to `%20` as URLs typically do not like spaces in them. You can remove if you don't need it.